# Python TCP Relay/Proxy Server locking up

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, proxy

I have a very simple Python Proxy Server that I've setup.  Its purpose is to take a TCP stream (video) and forward that TCP stream to several clients (currently just testing with one to start).    Everything works great until I try to forward *(o.send(data))* the data and then it will receive/send a couple packets, freeze and then about a minute or two later receive/send a few more packets and freeze again.

If I simply take the incoming data and load it into a variable it doesn't slow down at all.  And if I both load the incoming data into the data variable but send a random block of data to the client instead of the received data it also doesn't freeze.   I feel like maybe there is a race condition or something like that but .recv() shouldn't block so I don't know where the deadlock would be coming from.  As soon as data is flled by recv, it should be able to send it right?   And then rinse/repeat indefinitely.  I can check the CPU utilization with top -bn1 and the python script doesn't appear to be using any cpu at all.

The deadlock happens between .recv()  and .send().

If I put in a debug print it'll print "Data received!" ..... pause ... "Data Sent!" "Data Received!"....

```
import socket
# Listen for gstreamer TCP stream. 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("192.168.1.1", 911))
s.listen(5)

# Connect to the video player
o = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
o.connect(("192.168.2.2",910))

clientsocket, address = s.accept()

while 1:
# Receive the video data. 
     data = clientsocket.recv(4096)
# Forward it to the video player
     o.send(data)
     print 'o'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does the client look like?

Comment: I've tried it both with a .NET windows app that plays back video streams and just a dummy Python client that looks just like this proxy server minus the 'o' socket.  The performance is the same either way.

The .NET windows app works without the python proxy server in the middle, so I know it happily receives this data at a sufficient rate without a middle man.

Comment: Actually it looks like it might be a problem with just reading the data.   I tweaked the relay server code to just add each packet to an array and it's deadlocking in the exact same fashion. 

e.g. 

data.append(clientsocket.recv(4096))

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct ettiquete is with StackOverflow but I found the problem I think.   It ended up being a bad NIC that wasn't playing nice.

Comment: Write the answer yourself and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the NICs was faulty.  I swapped the NIC and it worked fine.  Not sure why it presented itself in this one way but at least I found the solution.